# Angular service on more than one page

Tags: angularjs, module, factory

I'm doing an API dashboard and I need to split the Login Page from the rest of the application, because of template reasons.

I created a service using a factory, like this:

```
angular.module('dashboard').factory('$api', function() {
    var api_url = 'https://my.great.app/api/';
    return {
      resolve:function(path){
        return api_url + '/' + path;
      }
    };
});
```

How can I share this with some other?

I'm a real new be on angular, I'm a little bit confused about using bower, grunt, nodes js and so on...

D.

Comment: You can inject the service into your controllers. angular.module('dashboard').controller(function($scope, $api) {...});. Services are singletons, so one instance is shared between all your controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular have good [mechanism for dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

In your case you can inject factory to controller with next code:

```
angular.module('dashboard')
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$api', function($scope, $api){
    var result = $api.resolve('path');
}])
```

Comment: After doing as you propose, there was an error on injecting module dependencies, tomorrow I finally understand what's whrong! In the angular.module('dashboard') definition I injected my factory like so: var dashboard = angular.module('dashboard', [
    //....
    '$api'
  ]);
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

a tip:

create a js file to create your module and share it for other files, example:

> main.js

```
var App = angular.module("myModuelName", [])
```

so, now you can include this file in your HTML, this will share your App var to others files

so you will be able to do

```
App.controller("myCtrl" ['$scope', '$api', function($scope, $api){
    $scope.path = $api.resolve('myInternalPath')
}])
```

Services are a good way to share information between controllers